# What glob do i use to find specific letters in files for linux

Tags: linux, glob

I'm stuck on a question. I'm trying to get a command that will list any file that contains a, b or c in the file name.

I tried using $ls [abc] but that only outputs a b c .

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ls *[abc]*
```

If that doesn't work, tell us about what system you are on and what shell you are using.

Comment: i'm using the cloud9 terminal. I just tried what you suggested, and I got this:ls: invalid option -- 'e'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.

Comment: Curious.  Are there files in the current directory that start with a dash?  That would confuse the ls command.  try 'ls -- \*[abc]\*'.  Some versions of ls use the double dash as a way to turn off option processing for the rest of the command line, so files that start with a dash aren't processed as arguments.

Comment: I didn't see any files that started with a dash, but that's good to know for the future. thank you!